# SQL Server what indexes to create

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a simple table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DocModHistory
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
  [DocID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [InsDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DocModHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and I have two select queries:

```sql
SELECT dh.BranchID, MAX(dh.ID) as MaxID FROM DocModHistory dh WHERE dh.UserID = @p_UserID GROUP BY dh.BranchID
```

and

```sql
SELECT dh.DocID, MAX(dh.ID) as MaxID FROM DocModHistory dh WHERE dh.UserID = @p_UserID GROUP BY dh.DocID
```

Could you tell me please what indexes should I create? 
Shall I create individual indexes for UserID, BranchID, DocID, or do I need multi-column indexes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index for `UserID` with Included columns `BranchID`, `ID` and `DocID`

So something like

```
CREATE INDEX IX_UserID ON DocModHistory (UserID) INCLUDE (BranchID, ID ,DocID);
```

Comment: So it is not necessary to create two indexes? Can SQL Server use the index you suggested for both queries with the same performance? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it can use the query for both as you filter both on `UserID`, and the included columns would then be used as part of the query, instead of a key lookup.